# custom handler defaultExecutablePath from azure pipeline artifacts

Tags: go, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Hello I created a golang custom handler azure function, i deployed it directly from VS code and it worked like a charm.

I wanted to add some ci/cd with azure devops pipelines and i managed to build an artifact and have it published in the project's published artifacts here is the .yml file

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: GoTool@0
  inputs:
    version: '1.16'

- task: Go@0
  displayName: 'Build Application Binary'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/my-project/src/cmd/httpport'
    arguments: '-ldflags="-s -w" -o $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/bombastic'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archiving binaries ... '
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
  
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'publishing build artifacts'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
```

I download the artifact published, unzip it and run it locally no problem.

I created a release (feature Releases in  azure pipelines) using the artifact and the artifact gets pushed to the azure function custom handler.

I go check the azure function app files  and the structure is bombastic/bombastic
bombastic being the name of the function, and **/bombastic** being the linux executable that normally you can call by ./bombastic.

this is the host file

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Trace"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  },
  "customHandler": {
    "description": {
      "defaultExecutablePath": "bombasticv",
      "arguments": []
    },
    "enableForwardingHttpRequest": true
  }
}
```

when I hit the function URL i get a not found 404.

Any help on getting the azure function custom handler to work with azure pipeline artifacts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The way I had set it up, it was zipping only the executable, I made it so the zip folder included the host.json and function folders and it worked.

Comment: Can you please publish the working .yaml?